# How to set `run-name` conditionally in a github workflow

Tags: github

Is it possible to conditionally set `run-name` in a github workflow? My workflow can either be triggered from the current repo (ci-systems) with the use of workflow_dispatch, or through the use of `workflow_call` from another repo's workflow_dispatch.

I would love to do something like the following to have the run-name set as `My Regression tests: Version_A + ci-systems: my_branch` for example.

```yaml
name: my tests
run-name: >-
  if [[ ${{ github.event.repository.name }} == "ci-systems" ]]; then
    My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }} + ci-systems: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  else
    My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }}


on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      my_version:
        type: string
        default: Version_O
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      my_version:
        type: string
        default: Version_X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is found to be:

```yaml
run-name: >-
  ${{ github.event.repository.name == 'ci-systems'
    && format('My Regression tests: drv:{0} + ci-systems:{1}',
              inputs.my_version,
              github.head_ref || github.ref_name)
    || format('My Regression tests: {0}', inputs.my_version) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to conditionally set the run-name in a GitHub workflow. You can use the if keyword to create an expression that determines the value of the run-name. In your case, you could use the following expression:**

```
if [[ ${{ github.event.repository.name }} == "ci-systems" ]]; then
"My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }} + ci-systems: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}"
else
"My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }}"
fi

This expression will first check if the workflow was triggered from the ci-systems repository. If it was, then the run-name will be set to "My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }} + ci-systems: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}". Otherwise, the run-name will be set to "My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }}".

Here is the complete workflow file:


name: my tests
on:
workflow_call:
inputs:
my_version:
type: string
default: Version_O
workflow_dispatch:
inputs:
my_version:
type: string
default: Version_X

run-name: >-
if [[ ${{ github.event.repository.name }} == "ci-systems" ]]; then
"My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }} + ci-systems: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}"
else
"My Regression tests: ${{ inputs.my_version }}"
fi
```